# Php get method resseting url

Tags: php

i am submitting form using get method to a url which already contain parameter like

localhost/myfile.php?section=console

my form code is

```
        <form method="GET" action="<?=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>/section=console">

            <input type="text" name="cmd" />
            <input type="submit" value="execute" />
        </form>
```

when i submit this data through post type it submit data then it submit like myfile.php?cmd=blahblah
but i want to submit it to myfile.php?section=console&cmd=blahblah.

i can do this by using hidden field but i am insearch of other better way

Comment: Just make the current URL with the querystring as the form action

Comment: i didn't get the point, can you please explain

Comment: why dont you use "/myfile.php?section=console" as form action?

Comment: file name is dynamic it can be change

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a hidden field into your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="section" value="console">
```

If you are not interested in using hidden fields then rewrite your form like this

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>/?section=console">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a hidden input within your form

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="section" value="console">
    <input type="text" name="cmd">
    <input type="submit" value="execute">
</form>
```

Comment: i am already using this method, i just want to check if there is another method, when i use POST Method i didn't remove my section paramter. i thought may be there is another method.

Comment: @facebook-100005510415497 You can still use POST and in `myfile.php` look for `$_REQUEST['section']` instead of get. I didn't quite understand why hidden inputs are bad?